# How to get count 7 days data of mysql more efficient to chart

Tags: php, mysql, chart.js

I need get 7days "date text" and "data count" for chart.js create a chart.

**mysql table**

```
id
title
create_time (unixtime int10)
```

php

```
//get 7days
$now = time(); 
$day7 = array();
$day7_srt="";
for($i=0; $i<7; $i++){
    $d = mktime(0,0,0,date('m',$now),date('d',$now)-$i);
    $day7[$i]["d"] = date('d',$d);
    $day7[$i]["m"] = date('m',$d);
}
sort($day7);
foreach ($day7 as $key => $value) {
    $d = $value['d'];
    $m = $value['m'];
    $day7_srt .= "\"$m-$d\",";
}
$day7_srt=substr("$day7_srt",0,-1);  //"11-19","11-20","11-21".....etc

//get data count

$data_value = array();
$date_show ="";
foreach ($day7 as $key => $value) {
    $date = $value["date"];
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM  `news` WHERE  FROM_UNIXTIME(  `create_time` ,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) =  '$date'";
    $r_title = $pdo->query($sql);
    $r_title = $r_title->fetch();
    $data_value[$key] = $r_title["0"];
}
foreach ($data_value as $key => $value) {
    $date_show .= "\"$value\",";
}
$date_show=substr("$date_show",0,-1);   //show "3","5","2".....etc
```

Js code style

```
var lineChartData = {
            labels : ["11-19","11-20","11-21","11-22","11-23","11-24","11-25"],

            datasets : [
                {
                    label: "My Chart",
                    data : [1,2,3,4,5,7,9]  //mysql data here
                }
            ]

        }
```

I can do my idea, and it's work

But I feel maybe can more efficient do that?
any sugesst?

Comment: You can do this with a UNIONed series of sub queries to get the range of dates (ie, _SELECT DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AS aDay UNION SELECT DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY)_ etc), then LEFT OUTER JOIN  that against you actual table of data.